# Exception with code from a OpenHaptics manual

Tags: c++, access-violation

I am using a sample callback function which is indicated in OpenHaptics programming guide. But, I get SystemAccessViolationException and can't get rid of it. This is the function:

```
HDCallbackCode HDCALLBACK queryButtonStateCB(void *userdata) {
    HDboolean *pButtonDown = (HDboolean *) userdata;
    *pButtonDown = gButtonDownOccurred;
    /* We sampled the button down, so clear the flag */
    gButtonDownOccurred = FALSE;
    return HD_CALLBACK_DONE;
}
```

exception occurs in the line: `*pButtonDown = gButtonDownOccurred;`

Would someone help me please?

Comment: How is this function getting called? It seems to me that `userdata` is probably `NULL`.